# PowerShell Script working with Excel COM Object buffering on different Clients

Tags: excel, powershell, com, exe

I created a fairly big PowerShell Script working with the Exce COM Object to Output Data it read into some .ini files.
I converted the Script to .exe with the Win-PS2EXE Programm.

When I start the Script on my Fujitsu PC it creates and then populates the Files.
When my Collegue uses it on his Lenovo, the files get created (So it can't be a filepath problem) but there isn't any data that gets written into them.

**My Fujitsu**

- Windows Version 10.0.017134 Build 17134 *(Everything is the Same)*
- PowerShell Version 5.1.17134.858 *(Everything is the Same)*
- All Excels fully closed
- No Clicking around when it's taking a while
- Script version 3.8
- Microsoft 360 Account with newest Excel
- Same Excel File Used

**His Lenovo**

- Windows Version 10.0.017134 Build 17134 *(Everything is the Same)*
- PowerShell Version 5.1.17134.858 *(Everything is the Same)*
- All Excels fully closed
- No Clicking around when it's taking a while
- Script version 3.8
- Microsoft 360 Account with newest Excel
- Same Excel File Used

The Script itself works. It was tested and debugged over multiple Months and it always worked (on multiple, different systems) with no Errors.
Where could the problem be or what could I try to do?

Comment: are you both using the same file for testing?

Comment: yes, I'll add that too

Comment: thanks for the info! [*grin*] so, next would be ... has excel been run on the lenovo using the account that is running the script? ///// if that is true, then you will need to start adding some logging ... i would start with a simple `Start-Transcript` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I tried it with Start-Transcript (Thanks, didn't know that command existed) but it looks like that isn't it. It can read out a small bit of the Excel but then it just stops, there are no loops or anything so I'm sadly back at the beginning.

Comment: you are quite welcome! [*grin*] ///// so ... start adding diagnostic code OR use the debugging mode of your fave IDE on that lenovo system to see exactly what is going wrong. it SEEMS like the problem is with excel ... or the call to it. i am beyond my tech level now, so i will drop back to lurking. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't know why or how, but the Excel itself is broken after I transfer it to his PC. (All Permissions etc. are set so that the excel works and everything.)

I copied the Data in the Excel into a new Excel File, which I transferred the same way again (Network Folders). This time it worked.

All in all, the Excel File itself has some Corruption. I may look into it and if I find a Solution I'm going to post it here.

For now I know the Script has no Error and works on all other Systems, but if anyone knows what could've caused the problem, I'd be grateful to know!